# Sending personalised email with attachment using Exact Target / Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have a need to send a number of emails to a group of users.

These users will each have their own unique email attachment(s) and use one of 10-20 language/country specific template.   Imagine it being used for email out invoices.

Which API/Feature of Marketing Cloud / Exact Target will allow me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some info on it: [Email Attachments](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/email_attachments/)

The personalized content will need to be available to SFMC either on their FTP servers, a publicly accessible website or in the SFMC Portfolio.  You can create Portfolio items with the SFMC API.

The [AMPScript](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/content/AttachFile.html) required for the attachments is pretty simple, however there's not much available in the way to of error handling (e.g. what happens when an attachment doesn't exist).

You'll need to contact your SFMC rep and/or SFMC Support for provisioning.  There's a per-email charge.

Comment: So as I understand it I use AMPScript in the Template to include the attachment, and in that AMP script use a variable to identify which attachment.?  I guess I'm also interested in the fundamentals, what are the steps associated with creating and sending an email from the API?  (Pointers to specific API calls).    Sorry for the drag, just staring at a wall of API calls and can't seem to find the document which puts it all together.